# Cannot call set or create from with in a Model class in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm working in a CakePHP Model class, writing a function that is supposed to perform a whole bunch of manipulations on the model.  I'm trying to follow the skinny controller, fat model idea.  However, I don't seem to be able to call **any** of the model's functions from with in my model.  Something hasn't been initialized yet, because I get an SQL error when I do:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 681]

Query: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM
```

It looks as if the table name hasn't been set internally somewhere.  My model looks like this:

```
class Search extends AppModel {
    var $name='Search';
    var $hasMany = 'SearchResult';
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');


    function search($query) {
            $this->create();
            $this->set('query', $query);
            $this->save();
        }
}
```

I know everything the Model needs has already been created works find, because calling that exact same sequence of functions works fine from the Model controller.  Like so:

```
function search($query) {
            $this->Search->create();
            $this->Search->set('query', $query);
            $this->Search->save();
}
```

That works fine.  So what gives?  What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a naming collision with my function `search` and something deeper in CakePHP's call stack.  Changing the name of the function from `search` to something else (mySearch, for instance) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the `set()` method? A method by that name exist for both `Model` & `Controller`, but I've never had a reason to use it in the `Model` context. Moreover, your particular use *looks* like it belongs in the `Controller` context (though that's an educated guess at best).

If you're trying to set a variable named `query` that can be accessed by the view, then it needs to be in the controller. `create()` and `save()`, of course, are staples of the `Model` context.

Comment: That was an extraordinarily boiled down version of it.  It's a very detailed search function with multiple model manipulations (creating the parent and associated models based on multiple queries to the database and other models).  In the context of the model, the `$this->set($field, $value);` is the same as `$this->data[$field] = $value;`  The issue turned out to be a name collision between my `search` function and something deeper in Cake's call stack.  Changing the name of the function made everything happy again.

Comment: Glad you tracked it down. Too bad the docs for `Model::set` aren't as concise as your explanation.

Comment: Yeah, the documents are definitely rather lacking.  Makes the learning curve for cake a lot rougher than it needs to be.  Thanks for the suggestions though.